# Scanner - managing input from text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I’m working with java Scanner trying to extract product information from a text file called Inventory.txt.

This file contains data on products in this format:

```
“Danelectro|Bass|D56BASS-AQUA|336177|395.00Orange|Amplifier|BT1000-H|319578|899.00Planet Waves|Superpicks|1ORD2-5|301075|4.50Korg|X50 Music Synthesizer|X50|241473|735.00Alpine|Alto Sax|AAS143|198490|795.00”
```

I am trying to parse the strings and add them into an arraylist such that each element  in the arraylist would look something like this:

```
"Danelectro|Bass|D56BASS-AQUA|336177|395.00"
"Orange|Amplifier|BT1000-H|319578|899.00"    
"KorPlanet Waves|Superpicks|1ORD2-5|301075|4.50"
"g|X50 Music Synthesizer|X50|241473|735.00"
"Alpine|Alto Sax|AAS143|198490|555.00”
```

Following is my code:

```
public class ItemDao {        
    public ItemDao() {
        scanFile();
    }

    public void scanFile() {
        Scanner scanner; 
        ArrayList <String> content = new ArrayList <String>();
        try {
            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\.[0-9]{2}$");
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("Inventory.txt"));

            while (scanner.hasNext(p1)) {
                content.add(scanner.next(p1));
            }

            for (String item : content) {
                System.out.println("Items:" + item);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I tested this code I found that the arraylist is empty. Any help would be much appreciated.

java -jar A00123456Lab5.jar

Create an ItemDAO class in a dao package
This class will contain an static inner class which implements Comparator
(DAO = Data Access Object)

Comment: Have you tested the String extracted inside of the while loop, to see if the regex pattern is faulty? Please let us know the results of your efforts to debug this.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. When I tested my while loop using this regex "\\.[0-9]{2}$" I did not no elements got passed into my the content ArrayList.

Comment: I refined my regex to "(.+[\\|]){4}.+[0-9]\\.[0-9]{2}?" and now I am adding first two Strings into the ArrayList but for some reason not all. Nevertheless, I think that the bug is in my regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using a pattern, those can come in handy--but I'd just take each line and substring it.

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String temp = scanner.nextLine();
    while(temp.indexOf("|") != -1){
        content.add(temp.substring(temp.indexOf("|"));
        temp.substring(temp.indexOf("|")+1);
    }    
}
```

Just a thought--might be easier to debug with this way.

Comment: I would use temp.split("|") to give you an array of strings in each line.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a Scanner on a String, and a delimiter. 
Since the | is used in regex as OR combinator, you have to mask it with (double)-backslash:

```
sc = new java.util.Scanner ("Danelectro|Bass|D56BASS-AQUA|336177|395.00");
sc.useDelimiter ("\\|");

String name = sc.next ();
// name: java.lang.String = Danelectro
String typ = sc.next ();
// typ: java.lang.String = Bass
String model = sc.next
// model: java.lang.String = D56BASS-AQUA
int id = sc.nextInt ();
// id: Int = 336177
val d = sc.nextDouble ();
// d: Double = 395.0
```